# Marketing Cloud Download Metadata for Single Sign-On (SSO)

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, login, saml

In the [Single Sign-On documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_identity_providers.htm&type=5), it states there is a **Download Metadata** link available to retrieve metadata needed to setup SSO. I don't see this anywhere in the Security Settings in Admin.

Where do we get the meta data? I found this [Shibboleth.sso Metadata](https://auth.s1.exacttarget.com/Shibboleth.sso/Metadata) with an ET domain but do not know if it's legit and it also says "**2016 Certificate**" I can change the stack and it updates the login URL so I'm assuming it is?  Anyone know? If it is, what if I'm not using Shibboleth as the identity provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question looks like a duplicate of [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/233261/marketing-cloud-metadata).

However, you need to ask your Identity Provider to provide their metadata to you. I opened a support ticket to get Metadata and was told by them that we need to get it from our IDP if it's some third party identity provider.

Once you get their metadata, you can then create a key and either paste that metadata there or provide the attribute data in the fields while creating a key.

You can find some useful information [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231991/enable-sso-for-salesforce-marketing-cloud/234046#234046).