# Single Sign On (SSO) with Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) as Identity Provider

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, saml, activedirectory

There are other general questions regarding SSO [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/257967/marketing-cloud-download-metadata-for-single-sign-on-sso) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231991/enable-sso-for-salesforce-marketing-cloud/234046#234046), but I'm specifically running into this error when using ADFS as the IdP:

> Incoming SAML message is not properly formatted, or has elements which
>   are missing or invalid.
>
> Reason: SAML response reported an IdP error.

We're using the correct version of SAML and tried a few Claim Rules of:

```
LDAP Attribute: Emailaddress --> Outgoing Claim: NameID
```

I have also tried:

```
LDAP Attribute: SAM-Account_Name --> Outgoing Claim: NameID
```

And also:

```
LDAP Attribute: User-Principal-Name --> Outgoing Claim: NameID
```

which is outlined in this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=identity_provider_examples_3p_adfs.htm) and also [here](https://blog.rhysgoodwin.com/cloud/salesforce-sso-with-adfs-2-0-everything-you-need-to-know/) albeit is for Salesforce CRM.

I've also used the [Chrome SAML Message Decoder](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-message-decoder/mpabchoaimgbdbbjjieoaeiibojelbhm?hl=en) to pull the trace details and it seems that at least one of the claim submissions is correct. But for some reason, Marketing Cloud rejects the connection:

[image: SAML Response reported an IdP error]

Also the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_overview_saml_error_resolution.htm&type=5) showing the error just says something is not configured properly.

> SAML response contained an error - This message typically indicates
>   that the Marketing Cloud received a SAML message from an identity
>   provider with an error status code, indicating something failed when
>   processing the request at the identity provider. Ensure you properly
>   configure the identity provider and that it returns the expected
>   successful SAML message status codes.

Anyone have any ideas? It looks like I'm [not the only person encountering this issue](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000DkFDQA0), but there's no resolution on that issue.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to find a solution to the problem? :)

Comment: No, sorry I was not able to find a solution.