# Marketing cloud and SSO - MFA via Azure

Tags: marketing-cloud, single-sign-on, multi-factor-authentication

I've done all the steps required in the provided [documents here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000353677&language=en_US&mode=1&type=1).

So when trying to access Marketing cloud through azure apps it works fine, of course it sometimes will prompt for MFA (via azure MFA) which again is fine. Heck if you copy and paste the Marketing Cloud SP Initiated Link into the browser it takes you to the microsoft azure MFA screen...get past that and --> takes you to marketing cloud. All of this is perfect.....

Here's the problem; when you just type the marketing cloud URL in it takes you to the Marketing cloud splash screen for logging in? Then you can't log in because the user account requires SSO to login. I'm trying to figure out why Marketing Cloud isn't redirecting....i'm at a loss. Using SAML tracer in chrome it doesn't even try to redirect to msft azure. What would be the cause of this? What can i be missing?

Comment: I don't believe MC redirects, in this case, you users should be accessing SFMC through the signon url

Comment: @EazyE so https://mc.s{stack#}.exacttarget.com/cloud/ is not the signon URL...because when i got to https://[domain].my.salesforce.com for the salesforce CRM login it redirects me to the identity provider ALA https://login.microsoftonline.com/{a bunch of stuff right here for the SAML login}...  Whould the login URL be the Marketing Cloud SP Initiated Link? Because that link works IE it redirects to the microsoftonline login page.... Are you saying i should tell my users to use one of those two URLs or the azure app?

Answer (score 2):

I can't find where I read it at the moment, but when we set up SSO with Azure for Marketing Cloud I read that MC does not put an SSO login button on the page so you either have to have users log into the Azure portal and select the Marketing Cloud app, or, use the long obfuscated URL (Marketing Cloud SP initiated URL) that Marketing Cloud setup provides in the SSO settings window. It's pretty pathetic in my opinion to have to do it this way when Salesforce provides an SSO button on their login page.

[This other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231991/enable-sso-for-salesforce-marketing-cloud) has a comment which confirms this.

Additionally, at 8:29 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ixJkw4QiT7A) the author mentions you can't have SSO and username/password enabled for a user simultaneously so you need the SP initiated link for the SSO users. At 13:10 the author shows the two methods which were already mentioned, SP initiated URL or the Azure portal.